# Split list of tuples into seprate list based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, list, split, tuples

I have a list of tuple like this:

```
a = [(1, 0.0), (1, 1.0), (1, 0.0), (2, 0.36034115138592754), (1, 1.0),
(1, 0.0), (2, 0.0), (3, 0.9999999999999991), (4, 0.0), (5, 0.0), 
(6, -1.0000000000000002), (7, 0.9999999999999999), (8, 1.0000000000000002), (9, 1.0), 
(10, 0.0), (1, 1.0), (1, 0.0)]
```

I would like to split it every time the first element is 1.
I have tried with the groupby, but I need to have a different list of tuple every time because later I have to plot it and each of these tuple is a specific point.
My expected output would be:

```
[(1, 0.0)]
[(1, 1.0)]
[(1, 0.0), (2, 0.36034115138592754)]
[(1, 1.0)]
[(1, 0.0), (2, 0.0), (3, 0.9999999999999991), (4, 0.0), (5, 0.0), 
(6, -1.0000000000000002), (7, 0.9999999999999999), (8, 1.0000000000000002), (9, 1.0), (10, 0.0)]
[(1, 1.0)]
[(1, 0.0)]
```

Comment: Please update your question with your expected output.

Comment: Done, I thought I had written, sorry

Comment: @Ibrahim I think the last two tuples `(1, 1.0), (1, 0.0)` should also be included in the expected output.

Comment: Yes, they should be, it was to give the idea of what I would like to achieve. I add also the last two

Comment: @Ibrahim Is the length of all the tuples always same i.e `2`?

Comment: Yes, is always two the length of the tuple

Comment: `[sub.tolist() for sub in np.split(a, inds) if sub.size]` where `inds, = np.nonzero(np.array(a)[:, 0] == 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I here post the solution of @Mustafa Aydin so that other users can find the solution soon.

```
inds, = np.nonzero(np.array(a)[:, 0] == 1)
[sub.tolist() for sub in np.split(a, inds) if sub.size]
```